# Running PSSession from jenkinsfile

Tags: powershell, jenkins-pipeline

Within my Jenkinsfile, I am trying to open a powershell PSSession to a remote machine to install some software, but it seems to ignore this step and just run all the next commands locally, instead of the machine I am trying to PSSession to..

Here is my code:

```
pipeline {
agent { label 'slave-windows' }
stages {
    stage('Parameters') {
        steps {
            script {
            properties([
                parameters([
                            string(name: 'VM_NAME', defaultValue: '', description: 'Enter the VM name'),
                ])
            ])
            }
        }
    }
    stage('install') {
        steps {
            powershell """
                Enter-PSSession ${params.VM_NAME}
                New-Item "C:\\salt" -itemType Directory
                [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
                Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://repo.saltproject.io/windows/Salt-Minion-3004.2-Py3-AMD64-Setup.exe" -OutFile “C:\\salt\\Salt-Minion-3004.2-Py3-AMD64-Setup.exe"
                C:\\salt\\Salt-Minion-3004.2-Py3-AMD64-Setup.exe /S /master=master /minion-name=${params.VM_NAME}
            """
        }
    }
}
```

I don't see any output in the build log regarding the PSSession command, but it goes ahead and runs all the remaining steps locally on the windows slave instead. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`Enter-PSSession` is for interactive use only. For scripting, use `Invoke-Command`:

```
powershell '''
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $env:VM_NAME -ScriptBlock {
        # code to run on the remote machine
    }
'''
```

- Note that using [Groovy string interpolation is very insecure](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#string-interpolation), because it is vulnerable to script injection and secret things like credentials may be logged. Shell scripts should always be single-quoted or triple-single quoted so this is not possible. Pass pipeline parameters as environment variables, which is easy because they become environment vars automatically. In the sample above, it is PowerShell that resolves `$env:VM_NAME`, not Groovy. To pass script variables, use [`withEnv`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#withenv-set-environment-variables).
- If necessary use `-Credential` parameter to use different credentials.
- In your case it shouldn't be necessary, but for more complex scenarios you can use `New-PSSession` to explicitly create a session and pass it for `-Session` argument of `Invoke-Command`. This would allow you to switch back and forth between remote and local session.

Comment: Hi, thanks - I used the invoke-command as you suggested and it all works except the last line: 
`C:\salt\Salt-Minion-3004.2-Py3-AMD64-Setup.exe /S /master=master /minion-name=computer /start-minion=1`
It seems to run, but does not return any output, and when I log onto the machine, I see that indeed the software was not installed:

If i log into the computer and run the same command locally though, it works just fine. Any idea?

Comment: @zorro1224 I can only guess. Maybe it depends on the account you are using to log into the VM. Are you using the same account as Jenkins when you manually log into the machine? Also try to enable logging for that setup.